# Neo4j High availability setup in Azure VMs

Tags: azure, neo4j, high-availability

I am about to setup Neo4j HA on Azure VMs, 
what is the best arrangement of the VMs in azure availability set to provide HA for Neo4j.
I think if i put all the VMs in one availability set there could be a chance that Azure Shut down some of our VMs at the same time instead one and this could lead us to the situation that the Neo4j cluster can not create the quorum for writing the data.
it there any advice to setup Neo4j HA in Azure Cloud environment?

Comment: This question belongs on ServerFault, not StackOverflow. It's not a programming question.

Comment: Yet @Farvashani This is an intriguing question, please tweet me at my handle brijrajsingh   lets get discussing

Comment: I am fallowing this from serverFault.
@Brij  I will tweet you

Comment: Moved to serverFault http://serverfault.com/questions/744425/neo4j-ha-in-azure-iaas-vms-and-availability-set